# TFS Setup and configuration guide (for code revision control)

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to Microsoft TFS, just installed version 2013 on our servers at work. We seek to exchange our current old version of Perforce revision control system for TFS. Both to eliminate costs (TFS is included in our MSDN license) and since we almost exclusively use Microsoft this seems like the right way to go.

Anyway, I have been looking into guide and/or tutorials and I haven't found any good ones for configuring the TFS for source code revision control, do you have any suggestions? The other features of TFS are things we'll take a look at at a later date as of now I think.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the [ALM Rangers](http://aka.ms/vsarsolutions)' guides, in particular the [Version Control (ex Branching and Merging) Guide](http://aka.ms/treasure18).

Answer (score 0):

Start with anything other than the Rangers branching guidance!

I would suggest that you create your team project with a Git repository and move forward from there. You may have to do a little work to get your code into Git from Perforce but in the long run you will be much happier. There is a script that is part of Git to pull history if you need it (would recommend ditching it) and the general process to move from server to distributed can be found here:

http://nakedalm.com/migrating-source-perforce-git-vso/

P.s. I am an ALM Ranger and I would never recommend their guidance. It is dated in the extreme even for SVCS and it favours a source promotion release model rather than than a more modern and less dysfunctional binary promotion model favoured by TFS. Even if you are going to use TFVC you should never do source promotion.